# Excel VBA Right Function Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, date-time

I'm trying to automatically update the date range on the top of my report in Excel based on the date range from data I download from a text database. In the below listed macro I get a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch on `PEndDt = Right(PaidDateRange, 8)`.

I think the Date variable, PEndDt, does not like getting a String. But I've assigned strings to Date variables in other macros! I don't now how to fix this. Help please.

```
Sub test()

Dim PEndDt As Date
Dim PaidDateRange As String

PaidDateRange = "PAID DATE  1/01/13 -  9/31/13"
PEndDt = Right(PaidDateRange, 8)
Range("A1") = "Report thru " & Format(PEndDt, "Long Date")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the string.

9/31/13 is not a valid date.

9/31/2013 is also not a valid date.

Comment: +1 Good Catch, I updated my post to parse the string and use DateSerial()

Comment: Thank you! Some times I get so caught up in the code that I miss simple things like the fact that there are not 31 days in September. My macro now works.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse the string into month,day,year format

```
Dim itemDate as String
itemDate = Right(PaidDateRange, 8)

PEndDt = DateSerial(Right(itemDate, 2), Left(itemDate, 2), Mid(itemDate, 4, 2))
```

---

If your just putting it back into a string why convert to date?

```
Range("A1") = "Report thru " & Right(PaidDateRange, 8)
```

Comment: I chose to convert to a date type variable so the leading space would disappear. Because I am getting this data from a text database, there may be a space in front of the date. The easiest way to process this space out is to use a Date format variable. It turns " 9/01/13" into "9/1/2013" without any additional code. It also allows for "12/01/13" to be parsed correctly.